# preg_match_all is matching "(-)" with "Caucasian/Non-Hispanic"

Tags: php

I want a identify a string if it contatins "(-)" all there characters.

The following code checks if a string contatins a range like "(18 - 35)" if yes then it will take 18 into $min and 35 into $max.

But my if statement if also matching with "Caucasian/Non-Hispanic". how do you fix this ?

```
if (preg_match('(-)', $data[$demographicRequirement[$i]])){
                        if($demographicRequirement[$i] == "age_group" || $demographicRequirement[$i] == "Age" ||
                            $demographicRequirement[$i] == "Age_group" ||  $demographicRequirement[$i] == "age"){
                                preg_match_all('/\((.*)-/', $data[$demographicRequirement[$i]], $matches);
                                $min = intval($matches[1][0]);
                                preg_match_all('/\-(.*)\)/', $data[$demographicRequirement[$i]], $matches);
                                $max = intval($matches[1][0]);
                                $date = new DateTime('now');
                                date_sub($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string($min . " years"));
                                $minAge = date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
                                $date = new DateTime('now');
                                date_sub($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string($max . " years"));
                                $maxAge = date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
                                $whereCondition[] = "(" . "date_of_birth" . " BETWEEN '" . $maxAge . "' AND '" . $minAge . "')";
                        }else{
                            preg_match_all('/\((.*)-/', $data[$demographicRequirement[$i]], $matches);
                            $min = intval($matches[1][0]);
                            preg_match_all('/\-(.*)\)/', $data[$demographicRequirement[$i]], $matches);
                            $max = intval($matches[1][0]);
                            $whereCondition[] = "(" . $demographicRequirement[$i] . " BETWEEN " . $min . " AND " . $max . ")";
                        }
                    }else{
                        $whereCondition[] = $demographicRequirement[$i] . " ='" . $data[$demographicRequirement[$i]]. "'";
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, assuming that the string can contain spaces as your example does, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
\((\d{1,2})\s*-\s*(\d{2})\)
```

Now the breakdown:

- \( and \) match literal parenthesis
- \d looks for a digit (same as [0-9])
- {x,y} means "length between", while {x} means "exactly this many"
- \s* is optional whitespace, depends if it's mandatory or not

And each part is enclosed in parenthesis as a capturing group, so you can find them in the $matches array, [1] will be your $min value and [2] your $max value, which simplifies your parsing.

Putting it all together:

```
if(preg_match('/\((\d{1,2})\s*-\s*(\d{2})\)/', $data[$demographicRequirement[$i]], $matches) === 1) {
    $min = $matches[1];
    $max = $matches[2];
}
```

This matches "(18 - 25)", "(18-25)" and "(8-18)", but no text.

Hope it helps